# how to find the adjoint system associated to a differential equation system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimal-control

While proving an optimal control theorem concerning the controlability criterion they used the following :

consider the system:
$$
(S):
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=A(t) x(t)+B(t) u(t)\\
x(t_0)=0
\end{cases}
$$
where $A(t)$, $B(t)$ are two matrices and $u(t)$ is the control. The adjoint system associated to the system $(S)$ is given by:

$$
(S^*):
\begin{cases}
\frac{dz(t)}{dt}=-A^*(t) z(t)\\
y(t)=B^*(t)z(t)\\
z(t_0)=z_0
\end{cases}
$$

I really don't have any clue how they did derive such adjoint system, even on the net I didn't find any method describing how to do it ! does anyone have an idea or maybe  the answer ? thank you for your time.

Comment: Hello Houda. Your question is not clear. Generally, in optimal control theory, the adjoint system is that of the Pontryagin Maximum Principle (PMP), but your system $S^*$ differs from it by the initial condition on $z$ (PMP ask for a final condition). Could you tell me what is the conclusion of the theorem about controllable to which you  refer?

Comment: Hello @RafaelRojas ! the theorem says that there is a duality between the the two notions contrability and observability, more precisely the system $(S)$ is controlable if and only if the system $(S^*)$ is observable. The demonstration is quiet clear but what I didn't understand is how they did find the adjoint system associated to the original one ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you should first investigate your reference subject to respective definitions. I think they use the ordinary definition of an adjoint linear operator.

You can look at [these](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3b01/057aa12a63fddd69b2f265445828f8df4d41.pdf) lecture notes, Section 7.4.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @OrangeSherbet Fixed